# How to achieve ionic modal auto-dismiss on clicking outside or hardware back button

Tags: ionic-framework, modal-dialog, slider

Hi i am working on an ionic project, where in the home page there is a button on clicking which a modal will appear with a slider inside it. Now when i am opening the modal for the very first time its showing the modal with the slider correctly then i clicked outside of the modal and it's closed. Now if the click the button again, now the modal is shown but the slider is not working any more, it looses the slider property and pager. What i may have missed --

on button click this is the code --

```
this.modalController.create({
      component: VipModalPage,
      cssClass: 'my-custom-modal-css',
      componentProps: {
        uid: event.payload.uid
      }
    }).then(modal => modal.present());
```

I tried using `backdropDismiss: true` but no luck.

Code of the modal slider --

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-slides [options]="sliderOpts" pager="true" loop="true">
        <ion-slide>
            <ion-img src="../../../assets/images/01.png"></ion-img>
            <h2>Text Heading</h2>
            <p>Text Paragraph</p>
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
            <ion-img src="../../../assets/images/02.png"></ion-img>
            <h2>Text Heading</h2>
            <p>Text Paragraph</p>
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
            <ion-img src="../../../assets/images/03.png"></ion-img>
            <h2>Text Heading</h2>
            <p>Text Paragraph</p>
        </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

modalpage.ts --

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-vip-modal',
  templateUrl: './vip-modal.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./vip-modal.page.scss']
})
export class VipModalPage implements OnInit {

  sliderOpts = {
    initialSlide: 0,
    slidesPerView: 1,
    autoplay: {
      disableOnInteraction: false
    }
  };

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

This is the css part --

```
.my-custom-modal-css .modal-wrapper {
    height: 60%;
    width: 80%;
    top: 20%;
    bottom: 20%;
    left: 10%;
    right: 10%;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: As default behaivior of modal, backdrop dismiss is true so when you click outside , the modal will dissmiss and is false then clicking outside will not dismiss the modal. Second, till now i didn't know what you want exactly sinc ethe question is not clear enough. Does the modal contain static data? If saw nothing should go wrong in each time you open or close the modal, and if dynamic data( data gets generated on page open) then you should provide code related for the proccess around it..

Comment: it's static data, let me add the code of the modal slider

Comment: Add slider options object here and whole ts content of modal, and my-custom-modal-class ,and last thing, if you close the modal in normal way, next time when you open it, will it get the view normally?

Comment: not understood bro

Comment: Add the things i list in you question, the modalpage.ts , and the question i asked, if you put a button inside the modal, and on click you run function modal.dismiss(); will the modal open correctly next time? Or will give the same result as if you click outside to close?

Comment: bro done but same result, only first time it shows the slider properly, but next time its not sliding nor the pager is shown

Comment: Ok where is your modalpage.ts file ?

Comment: added modalpage.ts

Comment: Try modal in other way, const mymodal = this.modal.create({....}) and remove then, and under it put mymodal.present();

Comment: tried in that way bro, but no luck

Comment: Is it me or is the title not related to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved the issue, steps --
1. In modal.page.ts -- 
Created a function to load data in an array for the slider.
And called the function here

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.loadData();
  }
```

2. In modal.page.html --
   Using ngFor display array values in slider.

Now everytime the modal opens then it loads the fresh data and slider is working properly everytime.